# How can I get the actual image of an image file in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

When I use `iconForFile:` in `NSWorkSpace` class, I get the default Mac image file icon.

However, I would like to get the actual image that are previewed on the desktop.
How can I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the contents of the image file, use `[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename]` as in Wil's answer.

If you want the way the image file appears in the Finder — a preview of the image file's contents formatted as an icon — you'll need to talk to the QuickLook framework. Call [`QLThumbnailImageCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userExperience/Reference/QLThumbnailRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005055-CH3-SW4) and pass an `options` dictionary containing `YES` for the [`kQLThumbnailOptionIconModeKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userExperience/Reference/QLThumbnailRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kQLThumbnailOptionIconModeKey) key.

Comment: This works very well! However, it is not showing previews for folders. I plan on using '''iconForFile''' from NSWorkSpace class but I was wondering if this could be achieved using QLThumbnailRequest.